# Python Iterating Through Dictionary With Tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I am designing a system that involves iterating through a pre-made non python standard dictionary with an iter function. I am trying to iterate through the tuples but keep getting this stupid Error. Also, this error only happens half the time, due to a bit flipping function that messes with inputs

```
 TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Probably an easy fix, can anyone spot?

Heres relevant code:

In my main program:

```
for tup in crusherdict.CrusherDict(db2, fields[0]):
    log.write("VOTE\t{}\t{}\n".format(tup[0][0], tup[0][1]))
```

Place in Dictionary giving me the iter error:

```
    def __iter__(self):

        for i in range(self.__len__()): 
            yield self.db.fetch(entryName(self.name,i))
```

Heres db.fetch:

```
def fetch(self,key):
    return self.cache[key]
```

And entryName:

```
def entryName(dict, str):
    return (dict, "E", str)
```

Full BackTrace:

```
in <module>
if commands[line[0]](db, tempDict, logFile, line):

in cast
return inq(db, tempDict, logFile, ("INQ", tempDict["voterID"]))

line 100, in inq
for tup in crusherdict.CrusherDict(db3, fields[0]):

crusherdict.py", line 91, in __iter__
for i in range(self.__len__()):
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>
```

Comment: That is not the *"relevant code"*. Please give a [mcve] and the full traceback.

Comment: Could you show the full backtrace? I can't find where the TypeError could be coming from.

Comment: Incidentally, don't write `self.__len__()`. Just write `len(self)`, that's what `__len__` is for.

Comment: @alexis still getting the error with that change

Comment: Of course you are, it's a stylistic change that has no relation to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback says the error happens at:

```
for i in range(self.__len__()):
```

We know that `range` expects an integer so this is hopeful, and indeed we can replicate the error message in Python 3:

```
>>> range((1,2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Therefore `__len__` is not returning an integer as it should.

Comment: @SeanJean I don't follow. Do you want to continue returning a tuple from `__len__` and somehow put a tuple into range? I can't see what either of those would mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `entryName()` returns a tuple of three elements. This tuple is used by `fetch` as an index into your cache. Since we have to guess from the bits you provide, I'm guessing your cache is a plain list, and needs an integer index, not a tuple. (Also you're passing an `int` to an argument you named `str`, so you're definitely confused about something here.)

Comment: But then the message would be `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Comment: You're right... clearly the code crashes before it got to this statement. The problem with questions like this is that there's never just one mistake. Have fun with it.